# Block Theme: How to use a different template on front page vs paginated pages?

Tags: customization, themes, pages, templates

I'm using block themes.

I'd like the front page / home / index to show some extra blocks plus the list of blog posts. However, I want the paginated pages (e.g. /page/2) to not have these extra blocks and only show the list of blog posts.

My question is: is there a way to use a different template for the index and another different template for the index's paginated pages?

Comment: note that index as a template has a fundamentally different purpose from the home/frontpage templates, which will be a hard requirement for understanding any answer you get, `index.php` and its block template equivalent are not the homepage template, they're the _fallback_ template at the bottom of the template hierarchy. It doesn't show on the homepage because that's it's purpose, it shows because a theme doesn't provide anything more specific. The same for post archives, or pages. Likewise the frontpage and homepages have very specific purposes, page 2 isn't necessarily the homepage